# UIImageView shows a discrete image when created programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I've got the problem. I need to create the UIImageView programmatically and add the image to it. But there are some issues with it. Look at the attached screenshots.
The first is the normal image, if I create the UIImageView in xib (storyboard) and fill it with my image. [image]

The next one is the image with some not smooth lines (like a discrete or blocks or etc).

[image]

### The code I've made

```
UIImageView *logoImg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(76.0f, 36.0f, 168.0f, 180.0f)];
logoImg.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[self.view addSubview:logoImg];
```

I have got two versions of this logo image (**logo.png** and **logo@2x.png** for non-retina/retina).
**logo.png** is 168x180 px.
**logo@2x.png** is 336x360 px.

Where I was wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try this **imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;**

Comment: Also try losing the imageWithRenderingMode call

Comment: logoImg.frame = cgrectmake(76.0f, 36.0f,image.size.width,image.size.height) . try this once?

Comment: why are you using imageWithRenderingMode?

Comment: I've also tried to lose the imageRenderingMode call. The problem is still alive.

Comment: I'd also recommend deleting both images from the project, cleaning the build folder, restarting xCode and re-adding the images.

Comment: @Ohnomycoco Thanks a lot man! It works! Make the comment as an answer for future users please. I'll mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend deleting both images from the project, cleaning the build folder, restarting xCode and re-adding the images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but try with

```
myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

This will display original image, may be work for you :)

Comment: Nothing have changed :(